# Get a list (array) of titles for sections from MPMediaQuery for use in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

(SWIFT) I am using this to return a query of local songs:

```
let songsQry:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
```

I can get each section title easy enough:

```
return (songsQry.itemSections![section].title)
```

How can I use the results of my query to return the correct info (an array of strings) for this function?

```
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return songsQry. ????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`let sectionIndexTitles = songsQry.itemSections![section].map { $0.title }`

What this does is create a new array by mapping over the `MPMediaQuerySection` objects and getting just their title.

Comment: Also of note, I wouldn't use the `force unwrap.`

Wherever you are doing the initial query, which I'm guessing is in `viewDidLoad` or something like that, make sure that your sections exist before trying to load the table.

Comment: I actually used this: let sectionIndexTitles = songsQry.itemSections!.map { $0.title }  and it works perfectly! THANKS